# HERE places REST apis returns web ui instead on json

Tags: here-api

I am evaluating HERE places APIs. However, the url does return the web page instead of plain JSON as response. Example query:

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code{YOUR_APP_CODE}&at=52.5304417,13.4111201&q=rest&pretty
```

I need the response as simple JSON but can't find any information on the [documentation page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-autosuggest.html).

Comment: In addition to what @zero298 said you might what to try removing the "&pretty" I couldn't find a reference to in the docs but I suspect that could be an issue as it likely influences the output style.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have already tried playing with various arguments. It doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to add callback parameter to the url. Example:

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code{YOUR_APP_CODE}&at=52.5304417,13.4111201&q=rest&pretty&callback=xyz
```

It is not clear from the documentation. I got this information from HERE support.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you were trying the request from your **browser address bar**, in which case the browser automatically adds `Accept: text/html` to the request headers⁽¹⁾.

Then, because the Places API has some web helper tool to play with available parameters, it returns html (the Web UI) because `Accept: text/html` was found in the request headers.

The solution to add `callback` is more a workaround, since it wraps the response with the value of the callback parameter.

Your initial request was actually valid. If you send it from your program or a REST client like Postman instead of from the browser, you actually get JSON by default, so there was nothing more to do. Of course, you can explicitly send the header `Accept: application/json` to be on the safe side.

*[1] Open the network panel of the browser developer tools to see what is sent.*

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `Accept` header in order for the service to respond in JSON.

See the example within the documentation [here](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/places-search):

```
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  --get 'https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search' \
    --data-urlencode 'at=37.7942,-122.4070' \
    --data-urlencode 'q=restaurant' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}'
```