# How do I get the JSON response from /places/v1/autosuggest in Java?

Tags: java, curl, here-api

I'm having some trouble with the Here API. When I run the curl command I get a JSON Object, but when I'm trying it in my code I keep getting HTML back. Can anyone please help me? What am I doing wrong?
This is the curl command:

```
 curl \
  --compressed \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' \
  -H 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5' \
  --get 'https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code=my_code' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id=my_id' \
    --data-urlencode 'at=48.13642,11.57755' \
    --data-urlencode 'pretty=true' \
    --data-urlencode 'q=Hofbräuhaus am Platz'
```

And this is my Java code:

```
private void searchForPlacesInMunich(String place) throws IOException {
        String link = "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest"
                + "?app_id=" + app_id
                + "&app_code=" + app_code
                + "&at=" + latitude + "%2C" + longitude
                + "&q=" + place
                + "&pretty";
        URL url = new URL(link);
          HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
          con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
          con.setRequestMethod("GET");
          con.connect();
          System.out.println("Length : " + con.getContentLength());

          Reader reader = null;
          if ("gzip".equals(con.getContentEncoding())) {
             reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream()));
          }
          else {
             reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
          }

          while (true) {
             int ch = reader.read();
             if (ch==-1) {
                break;
             }
             System.out.print((char)ch);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Some more info because I feel like I didn't explain the problem well enough:
The problem is: When I'm sending the GET-request via internet browser, it works fine (because it gets HTML as response), however in the bottom left of the page there is a curl command under "Take this request home" (the curl command is in the question). When I'm running the command in a terminal, I get the raw JSON response (no HTML), but when I'm running my Java code (also in the question) I am only getting the HTML response and not the JSON as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try with JSONObject

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Source from: [Get a JSON object from a HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073849/get-a-json-object-from-a-http-response)

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work though because I get a HTML response (HTML-tags and everything). I might have asked the wrong question. It's more about the Here API then it's about Java. I mean when I'm accessing the URL in my browser I get a normal site and in the bottom left corner there's a curl command that one can copy and get the response in JSON format (raw, without any HTML) and that's what I'm trying to get in my Java code

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to get JSON instead of UI: The answer was pretty simple. Just add a callback in the URL
Inspired by [HERE places REST apis returns web ui instead on json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220380/here-places-rest-apis-returns-web-ui-instead-on-json)